# Using an AC drill motor with DC?

Tags: motor, ac, dc

I have this motor from drill that is powered from AC. Is possible to use the motor with DC current?[image]

Comment: Is that a Makita? Aw man ...

Comment: is a Makita special?

Answer (score 2):

Probably. But be aware that the speed control will not work correctly and may, in fact, not turn off after you have started the Drill motor.

Most modern AC Mains-powered drill motors are so-called "Universal" motors. Such motors will run from both AC and DC power supply.

Comment: How am I supposed to wire the motor up? I can post another question though asking how.

Comment: Just hook the DC power supply where the AC would  normally connect.

Comment: I guess that means I need more dc power?? it wont turn and I think its due to the way they have it wired for ac.